# Finding general formula for sequence and prooving

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Struggling with the very first exercise in Polya's "Mathematics and plausible reasoning" [Find and proove general law](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKNNP.png).

1 = 0 + 1

2 + 3 + 4 = 1 + 8

5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 8 + 27

10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 = 27 + 64

I looked at the right part and found out $$ a_n = (n -1)^3 + (n)^3 $$  tried to use induction to prove, but no way expanded formula of $$a_n = 2n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 $$ would equivalent to $$a_{n+1} = 2n^3 - 3n^2 + 3n - 1 $$
so this was all I was capable of. Don't understand how could I get the [right answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJeso.png) and what's going on the left side of it.

Answer (score 2):

The left-hand side
$$(n^2+1)+(n^2+2)+\dots+(n+1)^2$$
can be written as
$$(1+2+\dots+(n+1)^2)-(1+2+\dots+n^2).$$
Now you probably know the formula $1+2+\dots+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.  Just apply this formula to each of the two sums.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I am too dumb and don't understand where the left side came from and how was it rewritten.

Comment: Try substituting $n=1,2,3$ on the left-hand side; you'll see that they correspond to the three examples you gave. For the rewriting, we're saying that if $a<b$, then $(1+2+\dots+b)-(1+2+\dots+a)=(a+1)+(a+2)+\dots+b$.